# config file parsing using yaml in c

Tags: c, yaml

I am trying to parse a config file using yaml. 
I could succeed the parsing as a whole file using the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <yaml.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fh = fopen("config/public.yaml", "r");
  yaml_parser_t parser;
  yaml_token_t  token;   /* new variable */

 /* Initialize parser */
 if(!yaml_parser_initialize(&parser))
 fputs("Failed to initialize parser!\n", stderr);
 if(fh == NULL)
 fputs("Failed to open file!\n", stderr);

 /* Set input file */
 yaml_parser_set_input_file(&parser, fh);

 /* BEGIN new code */
 do {
  yaml_parser_scan(&parser, &token);
  switch(token.type)
{
/* Stream start/end */
case YAML_STREAM_START_TOKEN: puts("STREAM START"); break;
case YAML_STREAM_END_TOKEN:   puts("STREAM END");   break;
/* Token types (read before actual token) */
case YAML_KEY_TOKEN:   printf("(Key token)   "); break;
case YAML_VALUE_TOKEN: printf("(Value token) "); break;
/* Block delimeters */
case YAML_BLOCK_SEQUENCE_START_TOKEN: puts("<b>Start Block (Sequence)   </b>"); break;
case YAML_BLOCK_ENTRY_TOKEN:          puts("<b>Start Block (Entry)</b>");    break;
case YAML_BLOCK_END_TOKEN:            puts("<b>End block</b>");              break;
/* Data */
case YAML_BLOCK_MAPPING_START_TOKEN:  puts("[Block mapping]");            break;
case YAML_SCALAR_TOKEN:  printf("scalar %s \n", token.data.scalar.value); break;
/* Others */
default:
  printf("Got token of type %d\n", token.type);
}
if(token.type != YAML_STREAM_END_TOKEN)
  yaml_token_delete(&token);
} while(token.type != YAML_STREAM_END_TOKEN);
yaml_token_delete(&token);
/* END new code */

/* Cleanup */
yaml_parser_delete(&parser);
fclose(fh);
return 0;
}
```

But I want to print the value of whole block. For example if I have following block:

`force_tx_margin: (key token)
(key token) default_value: 0x0 (value token)
(key token) efuse_bit_offset: 2564 (value token)
(key token) nwl_bit_offset: 484 (value token)
(key token) width: 1 (value token)`

I want to print the value token of each key token.
All help appreciated. :)

Comment: you want to store key-values of whole block and print them when block was ended ?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani yes exactly..

Answer (score 0):

This library provides SAX-like API for parsing yaml, for store key-values of whole block and print them later when block was ended, you can use stack. First you see `YAML_BLOCK_SEQUENCE_START_TOKEN` and after that you store `YAML_KEY_TOKEN` and `YAML_KEY_VALUE` into stack, after you see `YAML_BLOCK_END_TOKEN` block has been ended and you can print stack. for proper intention in your printing you can use variable for storing depth you are in when printing.

Comment: can you give an example? I somehow am failing to do so while using depth: